# Moving multiple files in a file structure to a created subdirectory within each directory

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I am trying to put together a script that will move files within a file structure into a folder that denotes the year.

Each of my customers has their own folder where I place their orders. Each folder then has subfolders for each year, and I move the orders into the corresponding year. I want to automate this process so that the files corresponding to a specific year go into the year folder in their respective customer folder for all files in each of the customer folders.

The foldername was made "2016".

The files are all .jpegs.

This is what I have so far:

```
FOR /d %A IN (e:filepath\*) DO mkdir "%A\foldername"
```

Comment: Are all of the files already inside their correct customer folder? How do you tell which files are 2016 files: is it in the file name somewhere?

Comment: Yea the files are all in their correct customer folder, and yea each file is from a scanner that labels them by date, the 2016 folders are empty and the files are just outside of the 2016 folder. In the past I did a 2015 folder but I moved everything manually. So I dont want to move the whole content of the customer folder because there is a previous year folder there, I just want to move the loose files into the 2016 folder